# Getting document from many-to-many relationship in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I have a many-to-many relationship represented by `role` documents.  A `user` can have many roles in a `project` (and a `project` may have many different users as well).  A `role` is essentially `{projectId, userId, roleName}`

I have a view that emits roles with the `projectId` key which allows me to easily find all of the `userId`s for a particular project, which is great.  However, now I need specific information about the user too.  I could of course just iterate over the users and query for them individually or user their keys, but I imagine there is a way to do this in CouchDB with only one query.

How can I get user information from `userId` with my roles view?

Answer (score 2):

In a CouchDB view you can emit `{“_id”: <userId>}` as the view value. When querying the view with `include_docs=true`, CouchDB will return the document with `_id: <userId>`. So a view function like

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.projectId && doc.userId) {
    emit(doc.projectId, {“_id”: doc.userId});
  }
}
```

might be what you’re looking for.